# navigation does not navigate to initial route of navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a bottom tabs created with Tab Navigator which has one button as below

```
<View style={{marginLeft: 10, marginTop: 20}}>
     <FormButtonNav
       buttonTitle="CREATE CALL APPOINTMENT"
       onPress={() => {
         setModalVisiblep(false);
         navigation.navigate('CallAppointmentsNavigator');
         setCross(!cross);
       }}
     />
</View>
```

the same Tab navigator has another navigator as its child defined as

```
<Tab.Screen
   name="CallAppointmentsNavigator"
   component={CallAppointmentsNavigator}
   options={{
   tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
     <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          {focused ? (
              <Image
                  source={require('../assets/af.png')}
                  style={{
                    height: 25,
                    width: 22,
                    marginTop: 3,
                    marginBottom: -4,
                  }}
                />
              ) : (
                <Image
                  source={require('../assets/BTappointments.png')}
                  style={{
                    height: 25,
                    width: 22,
                    marginTop: 3,
                    marginBottom: -4,
                  }}
                />
              )}
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: focused ? '#48d1cc' : '#ffffff',
                  fontSize: 10,
                  paddingTop: 5,
                }}>
                Appointments
              </Text>
            </View>
          ),
        }}
/>
```

The CallApointmentsNavigator is as follows

```
<CustomStack.Navigator initialRouteName="RequestAppointment">
      <CustomStack.Screen
        name="RequestAppointment"
        component={RequestAppointment}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <CustomStack.Screen
        name="CallAppointments"
        component={CallAppointments}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <CustomStack.Screen
        name="Appointments"
        component={Appointments}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
    </CustomStack.Navigator>
```

The problem i am facing is when I go to this CallAppointmentsNavigator it doesn't route to initialRoute rather to the second screen in this navigator. Why is this happening and how can i solve this ?